# Getting different input values from QLineEdit each time I trigger the signal

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I have a piece of code (Info_box)

[image]

That takes input values and uses another piece of code (DataManipulation) to make a bit of calculations to make a dataframe containing all the requested items.

This is the info_box.py:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from DataManipulation import DataManipulation

class Ui_ContactCreator(object):
    def setupCreateContactUi(self, Form):
       Form.setObjectName("Form")
       Form.resize(426, 300)
       self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
       self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(180, 20, 161, 241))
       self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
       self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
       self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
       self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")

       self.QU_INITIAL = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
       self.QU_INITIAL.setObjectName("QU_INITIAL")

       self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.QU_INITIAL)

       self.PRIX_VENTE_LT = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
       self.PRIX_VENTE_LT.setObjectName("PRIX_VENTE_LT")


       self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.PRIX_VENTE_LT)


       self.PRIX_ACHAT_LT = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
       self.PRIX_ACHAT_LT.setObjectName("PRIX_ACHAT_LT")


       self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.PRIX_ACHAT_LT)


       self.QU_ENTREE = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
       self.QU_ENTREE.setObjectName("QU_ENTREE")


       self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.QU_ENTREE)


       self.QU_SORTIE = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
       self.QU_SORTIE.setObjectName("QU_SORTIE")


       self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.QU_SORTIE)
       self.verticalLayoutWidget_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget(Form)
       self.verticalLayoutWidget_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 29, 160, 221))
       self.verticalLayoutWidget_2.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget_2")
       self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
       self.verticalLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
       self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
       self.QU_INITIAL_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
       self.QU_INITIAL_label.setObjectName("PRIX_VENTE_LT_label")
       self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.QU_INITIAL_label)
       self.PRIX_VENTE_LT_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
       self.PRIX_VENTE_LT_label.setObjectName("PRIX_VENTE_LT_label")
       self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.PRIX_VENTE_LT_label)
       self.PRIX_ACHAT_LT_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
       self.PRIX_ACHAT_LT_label.setObjectName("PRIX_ACHAT_LT_label")
       self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.PRIX_ACHAT_LT_label)
       self.QU_ENTREE_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
       self.QU_ENTREE_label.setObjectName("QU_ENTREE_label")
       self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.QU_ENTREE_label)
       self.QU_SORTIE_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.verticalLayoutWidget_2)
       self.QU_SORTIE_label.setObjectName("QU_SORTIE_label")
       self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.QU_SORTIE_label)
       self.save_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(Form)
       self.save_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(314, 262, 101, 31))
       self.save_btn.setObjectName("save_btn")

       self.retranslateUi(Form)
       QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

       self.save_btn.clicked.connect(self.onButtonClicked)


    def onButtonClicked(self):

       DataManipulation(self.QU_INITIAL.text(), self.PRIX_VENTE_LT.text(), self.PRIX_ACHAT_LT.text(), self.QU_ENTREE.text(), self.QU_SORTIE.text())


    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
       _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
       Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
       self.QU_INITIAL_label.setText(_translate("Form", "Quantité initial"))
       self.PRIX_VENTE_LT_label.setText(_translate("Form", "Prix de vente"))
       self.PRIX_ACHAT_LT_label.setText(_translate("Form", "Prix d\'achat"))
       self.QU_ENTREE_label.setText(_translate("Form", "Quantité achetée"))
       self.QU_SORTIE_label.setText(_translate("Form", "Quantité vendue"))
       self.save_btn.setText(_translate("Form", "Enregistrer"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_ContactCreator()
    ui.setupCreateContactUi(Form)
    Form.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

And this is the DataManipulation.py:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd



a = ''
x = ''
y = ''
z = ''
j = ''
def DataManipulation(val, val1,val2,val3,val4):
    global a, x, y, z, j
    try:
        a = float(val)
        x = float(val1)
        y = float(val2)
        z = float(val3)
        j = float(val4)
    except:
        print("Invalid Input")
        gazoil(a, x, y, z, j)
        

def gazoil(val, val1, val2, val3, val4):
    try:

        QU_INITIAL = val
        ARR_VENTE = np.array([])
        ARR_ACHAT = np.array([])
        ARR_ENTREE = np.array([])
        ARR_SORTIE = np.array([])
        ARR_STOCK = np.array([])
        ARR_MONTANT_VENTE = np.array([])
        ARR_MONTANT_ACHAT = np.array([])

    except:

        print("Invalid input")


    try:

        PRIX_VENTE_LT = val1
        ARR_VENTE = np.append(ARR_VENTE, PRIX_VENTE_LT)
        PRIX_ACHAT_LT = val2
        ARR_ACHAT = np.append(ARR_ACHAT, PRIX_ACHAT_LT)
        QU_ENTREE = val3
        ARR_ENTREE = np.append(ARR_ENTREE, QU_ENTREE)
        QU_SORTIE = val4
        ARR_SORTIE = np.append(ARR_SORTIE, QU_SORTIE)
        QU_STOCK = (val + val3) - (val4)
        ARR_STOCK = np.append(ARR_STOCK, QU_STOCK)


        MONTANT_VENTE = PRIX_VENTE_LT * QU_SORTIE
        ARR_MONTANT_VENTE = np.append(ARR_MONTANT_VENTE, MONTANT_VENTE)
        MONTANT_ACHAT = PRIX_ACHAT_LT * QU_ENTREE
        ARR_MONTANT_ACHAT = np.append(ARR_MONTANT_ACHAT, MONTANT_ACHAT)
        QU_INITIAL = QU_STOCK

    except:
        print('merci')

    frame = {'Prix de vente': ARR_VENTE, "Prix d'achat": ARR_ACHAT, "Quantité entrée": ARR_ENTREE,
         "Quantité sortie": ARR_SORTIE, "Quantité en stock": ARR_STOCK, "Montant Vente": ARR_MONTANT_VENTE,
         "Montant achat": ARR_MONTANT_ACHAT}
    global result

    result = pd.DataFrame(frame)
```

The thing is I want to keep getting a new set inputs each time I trigger the signal (save_btn) and concatenate the previous dataframe with the new one to get one final nice dataframe with all the data I have been inserting, but nothing seem to work. I've tried to set a loop inside the gazoil() but the interface would freeze and stop running when I hit the save_btn for the 1st time.

Comment: Can you explain "I want to keep getting a new set inputs" how does the inputs change? Do you mean outputs, because you have no function to change INPUTS after button click. Can you add example what you would like to see for result?

Comment: Hi there, that's exactly what I am after. I am trying to keep inserting values as inputs and use these input values to create a dataframe containing everything. Please refer to the second piece of code. If you noticed I can create one dataframe at a time, I want to concatenate all these dataframes to create one dataframe. I hope I'm making sense and thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to make some calculations based on inputs and then adding them to DATAFRAME each time we could do the following.

First we define our dataframe which we would use to store future dataframes. We use **None** to make it clear that dataframe doesn't exist.

```
 self.dataframe = None
```

Then after clicking button "Save Button" we check if input is valid. If it is not we print an error. Otherwise we pass input values and our current dataframe to function `data_manipulation`.

```
def save_btn_on_click(self):
    try:
        input_1 = float(self.line_edit_1.text())
        input_2 = float(self.line_edit_2.text())
        input_3 = float(self.line_edit_3.text())
    except:
        print("Invalid input!")
        return
    self.dataframe = data_manipulation(input_1, input_2, input_3, self.dataframe)
    print(f"{self.dataframe}\n")
```

In `data_manipulation` we do basic calculations, create a new dataframe based on calculations and cocatenate it to previous dataframe if it exists.

```
def data_manipulation(input_1, input_2, input_3, previous_dataframes):
    print(f"Received inputs: {input_1}, {input_2}, {input_3}\n")
    # Some calculation on current inputs
    input_1 = input_1 + 2
    input_2 = input_2 - 4
    input_3 = input_3 * 2

    # Creating current dataframe and concatenating to previous dataframes
    current_dataframe = pd.DataFrame([{'Calculated input 1': input_1, 'Calculated input 2': input_2, 'Calculated input 3': input_3}])

    if previous_dataframes is None:
        return current_dataframe
    else:
        return pd.concat([current_dataframe, previous_dataframes])
```

Full code:

```
import sys

import pandas as pd
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QGridLayout, QLabel, QLineEdit


def data_manipulation(input_1, input_2, input_3, previous_dataframes):
    print(f"Received inputs: {input_1}, {input_2}, {input_3}\n")
    # Some calculation on current inputs
    input_1 = input_1 + 2
    input_2 = input_2 - 4
    input_3 = input_3 * 2

    # Creating current dataframe and concatenating to previous dataframes
    current_dataframe = pd.DataFrame([{'Calculated input 1': input_1, 'Calculated input 2': input_2, 'Calculated input 3': input_3}])

    if previous_dataframes is None:
        return current_dataframe
    else:
        return pd.concat([current_dataframe, previous_dataframes])



class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        # Reusable parts
        self.dataframe = None

        super().__init__()
        self.resize(400, 300)
        layout = QGridLayout()

        label_1 = QLabel("Input 1")
        self.line_edit_1 = QLineEdit()
        layout.addWidget(label_1, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.line_edit_1, 0, 1)

        label_2 = QLabel("Input 2")
        self.line_edit_2 = QLineEdit()
        layout.addWidget(label_2, 1, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.line_edit_2, 1, 1)

        label_3 = QLabel("Input 3")
        self.line_edit_3 = QLineEdit()
        layout.addWidget(label_3, 2, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.line_edit_3, 2, 1)

        button = QPushButton('Save Button', self)
        button.clicked.connect(self.save_btn_on_click)
        layout.addWidget(button, 3, 1)

        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.show()

    def save_btn_on_click(self):
        try:
            input_1 = float(self.line_edit_1.text())
            input_2 = float(self.line_edit_2.text())
            input_3 = float(self.line_edit_3.text())
        except:
            print("Invalid input!")
            return

        self.dataframe = data_manipulation(input_1, input_2, input_3, self.dataframe)
        print(f"{self.dataframe}\n")



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    example = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This works just fine. Thank you, I highly appreciate it. There's also something I wanted to do but didn't mention ; Take input_1 as an initial quantity of something, I want it to keep changing with regards to the quantity solde and bought of that thing and, of course, show it in the data frame. How can I do that?

Comment: You could make another method which manages the quantity or make another class if you have multiple values that you define in creating the object and then make method inside where you can change values. Simpler solution would be method or just variable that you hold in App class and just change it. Also you can mark this question as a accepted answer by clicking the green outlined checkmark to the left of the answer.